# Two permutation iterators for classes in Python with and without a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, combinatorics, iterator

I am just testing out a couple of small classes for learning purposes. Here is my current working code:

```
class Permutation:
     '''An int list a permutation if starting at any index, one can reach every other index by
     repeated index accesses. The list [4, 0, 3, 1, 2] is a permutation: for example index 0
     stores a 4; index 4 stores a 2; index 2 stores a 3; index 3 stores a 1; index 1 stores a 0,
     bringing us back to that starting position after visiting every index.'''
     def __init__(self, p, start):
         self.p = p
         self.start = start

     def __iter__(self):
         class P_iter:
             def __init__(self, p, start):
                 self.p = p
                 self.start = start
                 self.curr = start
                 self.stahp = False

             def __next__(self):
                 if not self.stahp:
                     current = self.curr
                     self.curr = self.p[self.curr]
                     self.stahp = self.curr == self.start
                     return current
                  else:
                      raise StopIteration
         return P_iter(self.p, self.start)


class Permutation2:
     '''similar to the description above, but its __iter__ method should be implemented by a
     generator (not a P_iter nested class)'''
     def __init__(self,p,start):
         self.p = p
         self.start = start

     def __iter__(self):
         curr = self.start
         stahp = False
         while not stahp:
             yield curr
             curr = self.p[curr]
             stahp = curr == self.start
         else:
             raise StopIteration
```

I'm looking to clean the code a bit and maybe make it simpler. The code is fully working currently and generates the desired output.

Comment: Your indentation looks off a bit in a number of places. You'll want to check that.

Comment: @JeffMercado - I updated the code formatting.

Comment: @200_success - The current code is not broken, it works fine. Just need a review. Thanks

Comment: Whitespace is significant in Python, therefore it was broken code. Thanks for fixing it. I've reopened the question.

Comment: @200_success: Still not quite bug-free.  The doc strings, the whole `__iter__()` method of the first implementation... in this particular case, it's clear to see the intent... but it's _still_ broken code.

Comment: @JeffMercado I just noticed the same thing. I'll let this one slide, and just edit it.

Comment: Hmm OK then, I fixed the `__iter__`

Comment: @200_success - Thanks. I'll keep the format in mind for next time. Is there a way to clean the Permutation Class? As that's where am looking to streamline my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `Permutation` has basically equivalent code to `Permutation2`, but is doing things the hard way.  Therefore, I'll just look at `Permutation2`, particularly `__iter__()`.

> ```
>  def __iter__(self):
>      curr = self.start
>      stahp = False
>      while not stahp:
>          yield curr
>          curr = self.p[curr]
>          stahp = curr == self.start
>      else:
>          raise StopIteration
> ```

You shouldn't need to explicitly raise `StopIteration`.  Iteration automatically stops when the flow of control reaches the end of the function.

I find the LoLcat spelling of "stop" amusing.  However, flag variables are generally a bad idea.  You would be better off writing `if curr == self.start: break`, for example.  However, I'd just choose to write it like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.start
    curr = self.p[curr]
    while curr != self.start:
        yield curr
        curr = self.p[curr]
```

(Once again, the lack of a do-while loop in Python makes life difficult.)

Take care to indent your code very carefully in Python, as whitespace is significant.  Four spaces is a very strong norm, established in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).  You've used five spaces at the first level.

Answer (score 1):

- `P_iter` should have an `__iter__` method to fully comply with [the *iterator protocol*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

  ```
  def __iter__(self):
      return self
  ```
- Defining the `P_iter` class inside a method hurts readability and makes the class unavailable for anyone who wants to check the type of an iterator object.
- In `Permutation2.__iter__` I would use this approach to avoid the `stahp` variable :

  ```
  def __iter__(self):
      curr = self.start
      while True:
          yield curr
          curr = self.p[curr]
          if curr == self.start:
              return
  ```